# Powershell passing variables into other variables with parentheses

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Sorry for the confusing title but that is the best way I could describe it without posting the code in the title. I am try to take the $MajorCode variable and get it into the $filter variable. so that the output looks like

```
{((customattribute5 -eq "CurrentStudent") -AND (customattribute3 -eq "2101"))}
```

```
                NOT
```

```
{((customattribute5 -eq "CurrentStudent") -AND (customattribute3 -eq $MajorCode))}
```

the CSV looks like this:

```
Name             Alias       EmailAddress                  code 
DDL-PayPal       PayPal    PayPal0@test.test               2101
```

Full code is this:

```
$groups = Import-Csv -Path .\Book2.csv

foreach
($group in $groups)
{

$MajorCode = $group.code

$Filter = {{((customattribute5 -eq "CurrentStudent") -AND (customattribute3 -eq $MajorCode))}}

New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $group.Name -Alias $group.Alias -RecipientFilter $filter
 }
```

Comment: From the docs: _"Although this parameter is a string (not a system block), you can also use braces { }, but only if the filter doesn't contain variables."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, the `RecipientFilter` should be a **string**, especially if it contains a variable, not a **scriptblock**

Try

```
$Filter = "(customattribute5 -eq 'CurrentStudent') -AND (customattribute3 -eq '$MajorCode'")
```

<sup>Use double-quotes around the whole string so the variable inside gets expanded. Inside, use single quotes</sup>